# React.js: Do I need to separate each component to mixin to achieve inheritability?

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js, reactjs

Imagine this use case:

We have a component that displays a list of users.

```
var UserList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
     return this.props.users.map(this.renderUserRow);
  },
  renderUserRow: function(u) {
     return <UserListRow user={u} />;
  }
});

var UserListRow = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
   var u = this.props.user;
   return <div><span>{u.firstName}</span><span>{u.lastName}</span></div>
 }
});
```

Next, we would like to use this exact same component, except with a checkbox for each user (or adding a *data-user-id* attribute to each row). If using Backbone, I would subclass UserList and UserListRow and be finished with my task.

I cannot subclass in React, so a few options that come to mind, each with significant drawbacks:

1. We could just modify UserList with a *renderCheckbox* property. This is a textbook example of violating [open-closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). What if the license prevents you from modifying the source code? What if the source code is maintained by other team? What if the code is obfuscated?
2. We could copy-paste the code and write a different *renderUserRow* function. This results in huge code duplications - what if the *UserList* is hundreds of code lines long?
3. We could separate UserList into a *UserListMixin* and *UserListComponent*. Again - the same questions as in point 1 - what if, for whatever reason, you are not able to modify the source code? Furthermore - what if I want *every* react component to be inheritable? It would be really clumsy to split every component into a mixin every single time.

I am in a position of providing widgets for other teams to use - I simply cannot imagine every possible use-case of a certain widget. That left me wondering - what is the *React way* to solve this problem?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve here but it seems to me that you want to achieve a very high modularity here by not tangling components and creating a very tight coupling between them.

The two ways to really achieve that is to write the components in such a way that the teams can compose their own widgets or for you to "own the `UserList` component and then let them pass props to decide on what's supposed to render or not. Furthermore, I think you need to decide on what a widget is and how it's used before delving into this topic further.

Answer (score 0):

you should keep in mind that it is Reacts first goal to provide immutability and being predictable. This means an input that is the same every time results in an output which is also the same (simular to the definition of an algorithm). You should also keep in mind that react is then usefull the more nested your SPA structures are.

Respecting this fact you should design your components exactly this way.

In case of your checkboxes, there is a "second road". I personaly wouldnt create an extra component just because checkboxes are sometimes needed & sometimes not. But if its more than just a checkbox I'd tend to implement another component that manages and adds those "generic features".

This is an answer on how I would do it, but your absolutly right, that this creates questions. Probably this answer would differ in every usecase-

Hope this somehow helped